# Derivative of matrix $(A^TA)^{-1/2}D(A^TA)^{-1/2}$ w.r.t. $A_{ij}$

Tags: matrix-calculus

I want to find derivative of matrix $(A^TA)^{-1/2}D(A^TA)^{-1/2}$ w.r.t. $A_{ij}$ where D is a diagonal matrix. Alternatively, it is okay too to have

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}} a^T(A^TA)^{-1/2}D(A^TA)^{-1/2}b$$

Is there any reference for such problem? I have the matrix cookbook which gives results when $D=I$. But how is this general form evaluating to?

Answer (score 2):

$\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\n{{\vec\nu}}\def\m{{\vec\mu}}$Define the matrix variable
$$\eqalign{
B &= (A^TA)^{1/2} \;=\; B^T \\
}$$
and calculate its differential and vectorize it
$$\eqalign{
B^2 &= A^TA \\
dB\,B+B\,dB &= dA^TA+A^TdA \\
\big(B\otimes I+I\otimes B\big)\,db
 &= \Big((A^T\otimes I)K+(I\otimes A^T)\Big)\,da \\
M\,db &= N\,da \\
}$$
where $K$ is the [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix#2) associated with Kronecker products.

Write the function as
$$\eqalign{
F &= (A^TA)^{-1/2}D(A^TA)^{-1/2} \quad\implies\quad BFB = D \\
}$$
then calculate its vectorized differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
B\,dF\,B  &= -\big(dB\;FB + BF\;dB\big) \\
\big(B\otimes B\big)\,df &= -\big(BF^T\otimes I + I\otimes BF\big)\,db \\
P\,df &= -Q\,db \\
 &= -QM^{-1}N\,da \\
df &= -P^{-1}QM^{-1}N\,da \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial a} &= -P^{-1}QM^{-1}N \\
}$$
This is not quite the quantity that was requested, but hopefully it's still useful.

---

The desired form of the gradient can be obtained
by defining the tensors
$$\eqalign{
\n_{\ell jk} &= \begin{cases}
\o\quad{\rm if}\;\;\ell=j+km-m \\
0\quad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
\\
\m_{jk\ell} &= \n_{\ell jk} \\
}$$
with index ranges
$$\eqalign{
\o&\le\; j  \;\le m, \qquad
\o&\le\; k  \;\le n, \qquad
\o&\le\; \ell \;\le mn \\
}$$
Using these, a matrix $V\in{\mathbb R}^{m\times n}$ can be converted to its vectorized form $v\in{\mathbb R}^{mn}$
$$\eqalign{
v &= \n:V \;=\; V:\m \;=\; {\rm vec}(V) \\
V &= \m\cdot v \;=\; v\cdot\n \;=\; {\rm unvec}(v) \\
}$$
Applying these to the vectorized gradient recovers
the full fourth-order gradient
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial F}{\partial A}
 &= \m\cdot\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\right)\cdot\n \\
}$$
Contracting with the single-entry matrix $E_{ij}=e_ie_j^T$ yields
$$\eqalign{
A_{ij} &= A:E_{ij} \quad\implies\quad
\frac{\partial F}{\partial A_{ij}}
 &= \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial A}\right):E_{ij} \\
}$$
which is the requested gradient.

---

If you're doing this on a computer rather than the tensor approach sketched above, just use the `reshape()` function built-in to most languages.  For example in Julia one would write

```
# recover full gradient from vectorized gradient 
dF_dA = reshape(df_da, size(F)..., size(A)...)

# access the (i,j)th matrix component of this gradient
M = dF_dA[:,:,i,j]
```